# Line up swing components by edges

Tags: java, swing, alignment, vertical-alignment, layout-manager

Is it possible to line up swing components?
The components are in separate panels which both use flow layout. These two panels are in another panel which is using a grid layout.

[image]

As you can see there is a subtle difference and I find it annoying. I know that all of the jlabels [the rectangles in blue/purple all have the same size, so i think it might be because of the '+' and '*', but I'm not sure because the left sides of the first two boxes aren't lined up.

the panels

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
JPanel panel2a = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel panel2b = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
```

the first two rectangles (purple)

```
add1 = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
add1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
add1.setBorder(b2);
add2 = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
add2.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
add2.setBorder(b2);
```

the two blue rectangles

```
textFieldA = new JTextField();
textFieldA.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textFieldA.setEditable(false);
textFieldA.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
textFieldM = new JTextField();
textFieldM.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
textFieldM.setEditable(false);
textFieldM.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue));
```

the + and *

```
opA = new JLabel("+", JLabel.CENTER);
opS = new JLabel("*", JLabel.CENTER);
```

Showing that the rectangles are the same size

```
Dimension d = card1.getPreferredSize(); 
int width = d.width + 100;
int height = d.height + 50;

add1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
add2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
mult1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
mult2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

textFieldA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
textFieldM.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Adding to the panels

```
panel2a.add(add1);
panel2a.add(opA);
panel2a.add(add2);
panel2a.add(enterA);
panel2a.add(textFieldA);
panel2c.add(mult1);
panel2c.add(opM);
panel2c.add(mult2);
panel2c.add(enterM);
panel2c.add(textFieldM);
panel2.add(panel2a);
panel2.add(panel2c);
```

Comment: With the regular Layout's I don't think so. Netbeans align's components using a layout which (I think) it's very ugly to use by code. (It was a custom layout might it might be included in recent Java versions)

Comment: Sure, take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). `GridBagLayout` comes to mind

Comment: See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIU this could be achieved using [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html).  This layout would require 5 horizontal groups and 2 vertical groups.

[image: GroupLayout vertical & horizontal groups]

See [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) for examples (including discussion of that image).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556) for an MCVE.

[image]

Comment: I can see my weekend is going to be spent reading up on `GroupLayout` :P

Answer (score 6):

Cross container layout management isn't really possible (or at least I've never seen a layout manager that does it).

You can, however, think carefully about your layout requirements and produce some interesting effects using compound components and layout managers...

[image]

```
public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
                frame.add(new CalculatePane("+"));
                frame.add(new CalculatePane("x"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CalculatePane extends JPanel {

        public CalculatePane(String operator) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            Font font = UIManager.getFont("TextField.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24);
            JTextField field1 = new JTextField(2);
            JTextField field2 = new JTextField(2);
            JTextField field3 = new JTextField(2);
            field1.setFont(font);
            field2.setFont(font);
            field3.setFont(font);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(field1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JLabel(operator), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(field2, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(new JButton("="), gbc);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(field3, gbc);


        }

    }

}
```